# Yii2 store text in DB, limited to 1829 bytes

Tags: mysql, text, yii2, limit, innodb

I'm assigning to a model attribute the content of a text file. When I save it with AR to Mysql DB, innoDB table, mediumtext (I've tried with largetext, too) field type, it's truncated at 1829 bytes. I have no limitation rule in Yii2 for this attribute. Before saving, the full content is there. I have no clue if it's up to Yii2 or Mysql. When in Mysql I change the content of this field however, and import from file, then it's stored fully. I haven't found any infos on the web with such limitation. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ...
        [['text'], 'string'],
        or:
        [['text'], 'string', 'length' => 2000000],
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
$model->text = preg_replace('/,(\r\n|\r|\n)\*  /', ',', file_get_contents($file->tempName));
echo $model->text; // at this point still full content is there
$model->save(false);
```

Comment: Can you post model and actionCreate code?

Comment: Maybe there are `\x00` Bytes in the file

Comment: How can I check these `\x00` bytes? The text is split in the middle of a word, so I don't think so, but who knows...?